# Invalid regex group javascript

Tags: regex, forms, angular

I'm trying to validate phone numbers using this regex:

```
\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})
```

in angular 2 formbuilder Validator.pattern but I get this error about invalid group:

Invalid regular expression: /^(?(d{3}))?(d{3})(d{4})$/: Invalid group

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're passing it as string? If so you must double escape.. but you can pass it as RegExp: `/^...$/` so you don't need to use double escape for `\d` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validator.pattern` is part of JavaScript code that uses string literals that support escape sequences like `\n` (LF symbol), `\r` (CR symbol), etc. Thus, a backslash cannot be used with an unknown char, `"\d"` is an unknown escape sequence, and the backslash is removed (that is how JavaScript authors decided to deal with these scenarios).

Note, that all string patterns in `Validators.pattern` are anchored by default like this: `^` + `<provided_pattern>` + `$`. So, whenever your pattern contains alternations, make sure all the alternatives are grouped (i.e. do not use `"az|bz"`, use `(?:az|bz)`). Else, use a regex literal with anchors.

Thus, all you can do is to use double escape the special chars:

```
"\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{4}"
```

Or, use

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/
```

Capturing groups are redundant during the validation if you are not using backreferences.